# React Router V6 Async Route Loader

Tags: reactjs, react-router, remix.run, react-location

Have been checking out React Location and it has a very useful feature (Asynchronous Routing, Prefetching) and am wondering if this is possible in React Router V6. For example, they support Async Route Loaders

```
const routes = [
   {
     path: 'teams',
     loader: async () => ({
       teams: await fetch('/api/teams'),
     }),
     children: [
       {
         path: ':teamId',
         loader: async ({ params: { teamId } }) => ({
           team: await fetch(`/api/teams/${teamId}`),
         }),
       },
     ],
   },
 ]
```

I am sure it could be done (or added) since something similar is done with Remix Run.

Oh and also when is this happening (from reactrouter.com)?

***We recommend waiting for the backwards compatibility package to be released before upgrading apps that have more than a few routes.***

Comment: `react-router` doesn't appear to support this. Source for [`RouteObject`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/index.tsx#L807-L817) used by the `useRoutes` hook. `react-router` and `react-location` are, from what I can tell, two ***completely*** different and separate routing libraries.

Comment: @DrewReese yeah I was going to request it as a new feature to React Router v6 - I would use React Location just for this feature alone so useful. Any idea btw how to mimic this behaviour?

Comment: Probably with a Wrapper component/HOC that handles the "loading" side-effect. RRDv6 seems to be in favor of ***not*** expanding into specific use cases outside routing, preferring to offload behavior like this into wrappers, much the same way route authentication works now. If you need help I could take a stab at coming up with a wrapper that handles a loader function.

Answer (score 1):

This type of `loader` behavior is coming in `react-router@6.4.0` which should have an `alpha` release very soon!  See https://remix.run/blog/remixing-react-router for more info about the changes being ported over from Remix.

The backwards compatibility package was also recently released - have a look at https://remix.run/blog/react-router-v6.3.0 for more info.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I created a workaround for async loading for React Router: [react-router-loading](https://github.com/victortrusov/react-router-loading).

But it works a bit differently. Instead of passing fetchers to routes, you need to tell the router when to switch pages using the context in components:

```
// PageComponent.jsx

import { useLoadingContext } from "react-router-loading";
const loadingContext = useLoadingContext();

const loading = async () => {
    // loading some data

    // call method to indicate that loading is done and we are ready to switch
    loadingContext.done();
};
```